“お断りなのです” with the speaker as subject


A: 貴様！この私を締め出すのか！？
B: 酒がまずくなるネタはお断りなのです。


The second sentence seems to use “ネタは” as the object and the implied speaker as the subject, while also using the respectful “お断りなのです。” for oneself which I've always been told can't be used on oneself, especially not, as in this case, when talking to the queen mother.

B essentially says "I refuse anything that's going to make alcohol taste bad." Have you heard お断りします? It's the same idea.

@desmo I know what it means, but why is it in the respectful form when speaking about oneself? One would sooner expect the humble “お断りするのです。”

I don't know what "respectful form" is. A lot of terminology used in Japanese teaching is oversimplified. I assume "humble form" refers to 謙譲語. This manual is pretty clear: https://www.bunka.go.jp/seisaku/bunkashingikai/sokai/sokai_6/pdf/keigo_tousin.pdf

Ah, “respectful form” in Japanese is “尊敬語” which would be “お断りになる” or “お断りだ”. In theory this would be used with a subject of higher status than the speaker, never if the speaker be the subject of the sentence.

This is not 尊敬語. It's 謙譲語 I.

@desmo, you seem to be correct looking it up. Is this irregular in some way? For instance “お休みだ” is 尊敬語, correct? as well as say “お読みだ”?

After doing some research and finding the answer with @desmo pointing me into the right direction. I suppose I might as well provide my own answer. This “お断りだ” is not a respectful form of “断る” and doesn't so much seem to mean “I decline” but “not allowed” or “we don't accept” and is a common humble form often used in businesses.

子どもは入場お断りです。 -> “We refuse entrance to children.”


一人旅はお断りです。 -> “We do not serve solitary travelers.”

“酒がまずくなるネタは” is in this case in fact the subject of the sentence, not the object. Which also explains why “お断りになるのです。” was not used as normally say “お読みなのです” would be the respectful form of “読んでいるのです。” not of “読むのです。”
